# How to preserve formatting when inserting rows in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, excel-2010

I have a small program to insert rows in an existing excel file. On certain columns it is formatted a certain way such as centering bold face and Number columns. When I pull data into the excel file from an external source within excel the formatting is preserved. But when I use C# to push data into the excel file the formatting is stripped. Here is the code I am using

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37", exportPath)))
{
     conn.Open();
     OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(q, conn);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyNumber", record.MyNumber);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Revision", record.RevisionChange);
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Any ideas

Comment: Can you use Microsoft.Office.Interop? If so, you can restore the formatting after the insert. There's probably a better way.

Comment: Yes, i can use interop but that will be alot of work. That is why I have a file that already has the formatting. Let me know if any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

When working with execl files, avoid using the interop dlls. Best way would be to use the NPOI dll in case you want more functionality than simple sql.

you can easly applay fonts or any other formatting. i am sure it will also keep any existing formatting

free download from [codeplex](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) with lots of examples

Comment: I think this is what I am after. If it can insert thousands of records in an adequate amount of time Ill definitely use it. I will let you know what happens

Comment: please choose this answer if it helped you solve your problem. thanks